# Migrating Spring XML based app from Jboss to Tomcat to deploy in pcf

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jta, pcf

I am migrating a Spring XML based app from Jboss to Tomcat to deploy in pcf. But while configuring JTA for Tomcat I'm getting this error -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading

And I have added all the libraries:

```
transactions-jta
transactions-api
transactions
transactions-jdbc
atomikos-util
transactions-hibernate4
```

All the packages are from com.atomikos version is 4.0.6

```
<bean id="ecfdDataSource_test" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}" />
            <property name="url" value="${spring.datasource.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${spring.datasource.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${spring.datasource.password}" />
            </bean>

    <bean id="AtomikosTransactionManager"  
        class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"  
        init-method="init" destroy-method="close"> 
        <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="AtomikosUserTransaction"  
       class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp"> 

       <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="transactionManager_test"  
          class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"> 
       <property name="transactionManager" ref="AtomikosTransactionManager" /> 
       <property name="userTransaction" ref="AtomikosUserTransaction" /> 
    </bean>
```

Comment: I would recommend discarding JBOSS and Tomcat - run an executable JAR in Spring Boot.  XML bean configuration is outdated; annotations are preferred now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @duffymo ..But this project is very huge can't do that.. Looking for workaround

Comment: Get started now.  The project won't get smaller.